# Google Translate API v2 implementation

Tags: android, translate

I have purchased `Google Translate V2 API` and want to implement it in `Android`. But I am unable to find any example that implements this in `Android` or `Java`.

I just need a single example of implementing the current version of API in Android or Java. I have made all the required imports from the libs folder as per the `readme.txt` file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial Java API available for Google Translate [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/).

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code In Your JAVA method Or In doInBackground of AsyncTask Android**

```
try {           
        // See comments on 
        //   https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/
        // on options to set
        Translate t = new Translate.Builder(
                new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport(), com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)                                   
                //Need to update this to your App-Name
                .setApplicationName("Stackoverflow-Example")                    
                .build();           
        Translate.Translations.List list = t.new Translations().list(
                Arrays.asList(
                        //Pass in list of strings to be translated
                        "Hello World",
                        "How to use Google Translate from Java"), 
                    //Target language   
                    "ES");  
        //Set your API-Key from https://console.developers.google.com/
        list.setKey("you-need-your-own-api-key");
        TranslationsListResponse response = list.execute();
        for(TranslationsResource tr : response.getTranslations()) {
            System.out.println(tr.getTranslatedText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> You Have to add
>
> compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-translate', version: 'v2-rev48-1.22.0'
>   compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-gson', version: '1.22.0'

To your dependancy

[Reference From This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424349/how-do-you-make-a-request-for-a-translation-with-the-google-translate-v2-api-cli)

Comment: In Above Reference Link new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport() is not used to create Translate.Builder() so it not support for android due to some algorithm exception.