# How do you make a request for a translation with the Google Translate v2 API Client Library for java?

Tags: java, api, google-api, google-translate

There aren't examples on how to use Google Translate API Cliente library for java.

In this page Google suggest to search examples for their APIs but there is not a single one for Google Translate API: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples

Since I didn't found any example for Google Translate API I don't have any clue about how to use their official java library.

I want to make a simple request to translate a text (for example Hello World from english to spanish) with the Official library made by Google: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2 but there is no documentation or examples available for the public.

Does anyone have info about how to use Google Translate API client library in java, I already googled and I had no luck at all.

I already have included all the jars to my project, but I don't know which classes I must use or which objects instantiate to make a translation from one language to another. I have no clue at all. I just need a simple snipped of code like in the examples repositories for other Google APIs.

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? It's very unclear to me.

Comment: I've edited the question so everyone can understand what my problem is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a working example.

You need to have your own App-Key generated for your app (start [here](https://console.developers.google.com/)) as translate API is no longer publicly available.

For options what to pass into Translate.Builder() see [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.api.services.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsResource;

public class TranslateMe {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {           
            // See comments on 
            //   https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/
            // on options to set
            Translate t = new Translate.Builder(
                    com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
                    , com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)                                   
                    //Need to update this to your App-Name
                    .setApplicationName("Stackoverflow-Example")                    
                    .build();           
            Translate.Translations.List list = t.new Translations().list(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            //Pass in list of strings to be translated
                            "Hello World",
                            "How to use Google Translate from Java"), 
                        //Target language   
                        "ES");  
            //Set your API-Key from https://console.developers.google.com/
            list.setKey("you-need-your-own-api-key");
            TranslationsListResponse response = list.execute();
            for(TranslationsResource tr : response.getTranslations()) {
                System.out.println(tr.getTranslatedText());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will set also the 'referer' property in order to do successful integration tests from your PC, something like this: "list.getRequestHeaders().set('referer', 'www.myautorizedsite.com');"

Comment: What is the maven dependency for these packages? I am not able to find a working one.

Answer (score 6):

reference：
[Translate API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries)

template：

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;

public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    Translate translate = TranslateOptions.builder().apiKey("YOUR_API_KEY").build().service();

    // The text to translate
    String text = "Hello, world!";

    // Translates some text into Russian
    Translation translation = translate.translate(
      text,
      TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
      TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru")
    );

    System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
    System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.translatedText());
  }
}
```

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: TranslateOptions.builder().apiKey() is deprecated. Which is the new method to achieve that?

Comment: use `new builder` instead of `builder` @nanosoft

Comment: @grant: Do you mean : TranslateOptions.new builder().apiKey("GOOGLE_API_KEY").build().service(); gives error TranslateOptions cannot be resolved to a variable-> which is strange TranslateOptions can be imported

Comment: Use this in your AsyncTask Class: `Translate translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey("API_KEY").build().getService();` @nanosoft

Comment: @grant - Agreed. Thanks for the full syntax and call chain.